# Merging all Word documents in folder in c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm trying to merge multiple Word documents from a folder, and save it in another folder.

I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7582/Merging-Word-Documents-with-C) example and tried to implement the same method in my application. When i debug it it throws the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

objDocLast was null.

```
    public void Merge(string strOrgDoc, string[] arrCopies, string strOutDoc)
    {
        ApplicationClass objApp = null;

        //boxing of default values for COM interop purposes
        object objMissing = Missing.Value;
        object objFalse = false;
        object objTarget = WdMergeTarget.wdMergeTargetSelected;
        object objUseFormatFrom = WdUseFormattingFrom.wdFormattingFromSelected;

        try
        {
            objApp = new ApplicationClass();
            object objOrgDoc = strOrgDoc;

            Document objDocLast = null;
            Document objDocBeforeLast = null;

            objDocLast = objApp.Documents.Open(
              ref objOrgDoc,    //FileName
              ref objMissing,   //ConfirmVersions
              ref objMissing,   //ReadOnly
              ref objMissing,   //AddToRecentFiles
              ref objMissing,   //PasswordDocument
              ref objMissing,   //PasswordTemplate
              ref objMissing,   //Revert
              ref objMissing,   //WritePasswordDocument
              ref objMissing,   //WritePasswordTemplate
              ref objMissing,   //Format
              ref objMissing,   //Enconding
              ref objMissing,   //Visible
              ref objMissing,   //OpenAndRepair
              ref objMissing,   //DocumentDirection
              ref objMissing,   //NoEncodingDialog
              ref objMissing    //XMLTransform
              );

            foreach (string strCopy in arrCopies)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Merging file " + strCopy);
                //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Error shows up here:
                objDocLast.Merge(
                  strCopy,                //FileName    
                  ref objTarget,          //MergeTarget
                  ref objMissing,         //DetectFormatChanges
                  ref objUseFormatFrom,   //UseFormattingFrom
                  ref objMissing          //AddToRecentFiles
                  );
                objDocBeforeLast = objDocLast;
                objDocLast = objApp.ActiveDocument;
                Debug.WriteLine("The active document is " + objDocLast.Name);

                if (objDocBeforeLast != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Closing " + objDocBeforeLast.Name);
                    objDocBeforeLast.Close(
                      ref objFalse,     //SaveChanges
                      ref objMissing,   //OriginalFormat
                      ref objMissing    //RouteDocument
                      );
                }


            }

            object objOutDoc = strOutDoc;


            objDocLast.SaveAs(
              ref objOutDoc,      //FileName
              ref objMissing,     //FileFormat
              ref objMissing,     //LockComments
              ref objMissing,     //PassWord     
              ref objMissing,     //AddToRecentFiles
              ref objMissing,     //WritePassword
              ref objMissing,     //ReadOnlyRecommended
              ref objMissing,     //EmbedTrueTypeFonts
              ref objMissing,     //SaveNativePictureFormat
              ref objMissing,     //SaveFormsData
              ref objMissing,     //SaveAsAOCELetter,
              ref objMissing,     //Encoding
              ref objMissing,     //InsertLineBreaks
              ref objMissing,     //AllowSubstitutions
              ref objMissing,     //LineEnding
              ref objMissing      //AddBiDiMarks
              );

            foreach (Document objDocument in objApp.Documents)
            {
                objDocument.Close(
                  ref objFalse,     //SaveChanges
                  ref objMissing,   //OriginalFormat
                  ref objMissing    //RouteDocument
                  );
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            objApp.Quit(
              ref objMissing,     //SaveChanges
              ref objMissing,     //OriginalFormat
              ref objMissing      //RoutDocument
              );
            objApp = null;
        }

    }


    /// Merge a document with a set of copies

    // name = "strOrgDoc">
    // Original file name

    // name = "strCopyFolder">
    // Folder in which the copies are located

    // name = "strOutDoc">
    // The result filename

    public void Merge(string strOrgDoc, string strCopyFolder, string strOutDoc)
    {
        string[] arrFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strCopyFolder);
        Merge(strOrgDoc, arrFiles, strOutDoc);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the method from another class:

```
        string orgFile = @"C:\M-Files Add-on\Styrerom Protokoll\Processing\10\Dokument dlij.docx";
        string cpyDir = @"C:\M-Files Add-on\Styrerom Protokoll\Processing\10\";
        string outFile = @"C:\M-Files Add-on\Styrerom Protokoll\Ready\10.docx";

        DocumentMerge docMerge = new DocumentMerge();
        docMerge.Merge(orgFile, cpyDir, outFile);
```

Comment: `objApp.Documents.Open` apparently returned null.  Check it with your debugger.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just don't understand why.. I'm giving the method all the variables needed..

Comment: Paste `C:\M-Files Add-on\Styrerom Protokoll\Processing\10\Dokument dlij.docx` into an Explorer window, and see what happens.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the path exists.

Comment: Alright, well the code example you found on the Internet is very, very old, and uses COM Interop.  Check out [this example code](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/), which uses a more modern approach.

Comment: You can also check out the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).